# Dividir timeline en solo dos cards

Tags: html, css, flexbox

He tomado como ejemplo de codigo abierto, una timeline realizada con flexbox que he encontrado en internet, queria modificarla de tal modo que solo quedaran dos cards, sin embargo a la hora de ir sustituyendo/quitando elementos, la timeline se me queda desconfigurada de tal forma que las cards se colocan en forma de columna, una encima de la otra, de tal forma que no me sirve, intente modificarlo pero me da errores a la hora de ajustarlo. adjunto el codigo que tome. Mi idea es solo tener dos unicas cards (al menos por el momento), pero no se como configurarlo de modo que no se me desajuste el diseño.

Enlace con el codigo: https://codepen.io/paulhbarker/pen/apvGdv

```css
/* Media Queries */

@mixin mq-xs {
  @media (min-width: 320px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-sm {
  @media (min-width: 480px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-md {
  @media (min-width: 720px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-lg {
  @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    @content;
  }
}

$background: #f7f7f7;
$box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
$border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.4);
$items: 5;
$rows: ceil($items/2);

/* Card sizing */

$card-height: 400px;
$card-width: 450px;
$inner-margin: 15px;
$number-size: 35px;
$stagger: 180px;
$outer-margin: 90px;
$marker-size: 9px;

/* Colors */

$steps: #46b8e9;
$colors: #46b8e9,
#3ee9d1,
#ce43eb,
#4d92eb;
$timeline: #bdbdbd;

/* Calculations */

$container-height: $rows * ($card-height + $outer-margin) + $stagger;
$container-width: $card-width*2 + $outer-margin*3;
$head-height: $number-size + 50;
$body-height: $card-height - $head-height;
$marker-dist: $card-width + $outer-margin/2 - $marker-size/2;

/* Placeholders */

@include mq-lg {
  %arrow {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  }
  %marker {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: $marker-size;
    height: $marker-size;
    background-color: $timeline;
    border-radius: $marker-size;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 8px $background;
  }
}


/* Some Cool Stuff */

$counter: $items - $rows + 2;
@for $i from 1 through $rows {
  .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2-1})   { order: $i }
  .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2})     { order: $counter }
  $counter: $counter + 1;
}

/* Border Box */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Fonts */

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#timeline {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: $background;
  border-top: $border;
  border-bottom: $border;
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  p.leader {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
  .demo-card-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    @include mq-lg {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      width: $container-width;
      height: $container-height;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    &::after {
      z-index: 1;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: $border;
      @include mq-lg {
        border-left: 1px solid $timeline;
      }
    }
  }
  .demo-card {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 80px;
    max-width: 94%;
    z-index: 2;
    @include mq-sm {
      max-width: 60%;
      box-shadow: $box-shadow;
    }
    @include mq-md {
      max-width: 40%;
    }
    @include mq-lg {
      max-width: $card-width;
      height: $card-height;
      margin: $outer-margin;
      margin-top: $outer-margin/2;
      margin-bottom: $outer-margin/2;
      &:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: $outer-margin/2;
        .head::after {
          @extend %arrow;
          border-left-width: 15px;
          border-left-style: solid;
          left: 100%;
        }
        .head::before {
          @extend %marker;
          left: $marker-dist + 1;
        }
      }
      &:nth-child(even) {
        margin-left: $outer-margin/2;
        .head::after {
          @extend %arrow;
          border-right-width: 15px;
          border-right-style: solid;
          right: 100%;
        }
        .head::before {
          @extend %marker;
          right: $marker-dist - 1;
        }
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        margin-top: $stagger;
      }
    }
    .head {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 400;
      .number-box {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: $inner-margin;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: $number-size;
        line-height: $number-size;
        font-weight: 600;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
      }
      h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        font-weight: inherit;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        line-height: 1rem;
        @include mq-sm {
          font-size: 165%;
          line-height: 1.2rem;
        }
        span {
          display: block;
          font-size: 0.6rem;
          margin: 0;
          @include mq-sm {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .body {
      background: #fff;
      border: $border;
      border-top: 0;
      padding: $inner-margin;
      @include mq-lg {
        height: $body-height;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin-bottom: $inner-margin;
      }
      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    @for $i from 1 through $items {
      &--step#{$i} {
        $color: nth($colors, ((($i - 1) % 4) + 1));
        background-color: $color;
        .head::after {
          border-color: $color;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id=timeline>
    <h1>A Flexbox Timeline</h1>
    <p class="leader">All cards must be the same height and width for space calculations on large screens.</p>
    <div class="demo-card-wrapper">
        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>01</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Technology</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>02</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Confidence</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step3">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>03</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Adaptation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step4">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>04</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Consistency</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step5">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>05</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Conversion</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realizando un cambios en tu código, me parece que se obtiene el resultado que quires, primero en el wrapper principal que contiene las cajas del timeline, cambiamos el flex-flow a row para que contenga las cajas en columnas y asi presente las dos cajas que necesitas. Tambien elimine un margin top presente en la columna de la derecha y por supuesto se eliminaron las cajas adicionales. el resultado es este, recuerda probarlo en tu propio editor de texto o codepen. Saludos:

```css
/* Media Queries */

@mixin mq-xs {
  @media (min-width: 320px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-sm {
  @media (min-width: 480px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-md {
  @media (min-width: 720px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin mq-lg {
  @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    @content;
  }
}

$background: #f7f7f7;
$box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
$border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.4);
$items: 5;
$rows: ceil($items/2);

/* Card sizing */

$card-height: 400px;
$card-width: 450px;
$inner-margin: 15px;
$number-size: 35px;
$stagger: 180px;
$outer-margin: 90px;
$marker-size: 9px;

/* Colors */

$steps: #46b8e9;
$colors: #46b8e9,
#3ee9d1,
#ce43eb,
#4d92eb;
$timeline: #bdbdbd;

/* Calculations */

$container-height: $rows * ($card-height + $outer-margin) + $stagger;
$container-width: $card-width*2 + $outer-margin*3;
$head-height: $number-size + 50;
$body-height: $card-height - $head-height;
$marker-dist: $card-width + $outer-margin/2 - $marker-size/2;

/* Placeholders */

@include mq-lg {
  %arrow {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  }
  %marker {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: $marker-size;
    height: $marker-size;
    background-color: $timeline;
    border-radius: $marker-size;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 8px $background;
  }
}


/* Some Cool Stuff */

$counter: $items - $rows + 2;
@for $i from 1 through $rows {
  .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2-1})   { order: $i }
  .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2})     { order: $counter }
  $counter: $counter + 1;
}

/* Border Box */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Fonts */

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#timeline {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: $background;
  border-top: $border;
  border-bottom: $border;
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  p.leader {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
  .demo-card-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    @include mq-lg {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row;
      width: $container-width;
      height: $container-height;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    &::after {
      z-index: 1;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: $border;
      @include mq-lg {
        border-left: 1px solid $timeline;
      }
    }
  }
  .demo-card {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 80px;
    max-width: 94%;
    z-index: 2;
    @include mq-sm {
      max-width: 60%;
      box-shadow: $box-shadow;
    }
    @include mq-md {
      max-width: 40%;
    }
    @include mq-lg {
      max-width: $card-width;
      height: $card-height;
      margin: $outer-margin;
      margin-top: $outer-margin/2;
      margin-bottom: $outer-margin/2;
      &:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: $outer-margin/2;
        .head::after {
          @extend %arrow;
          border-left-width: 15px;
          border-left-style: solid;
          left: 100%;
        }
        .head::before {
          @extend %marker;
          left: $marker-dist + 1;
        }
      }
      &:nth-child(even) {
        margin-left: $outer-margin/2;
        .head::after {
          @extend %arrow;
          border-right-width: 15px;
          border-right-style: solid;
          right: 100%;
        }
        .head::before {
          @extend %marker;
          right: $marker-dist - 1;
        }
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        // descomenta si quieres el espacio superior
        //margin-top: $stagger;
      }
    }
    .head {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 400;
      .number-box {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: $inner-margin;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: $number-size;
        line-height: $number-size;
        font-weight: 600;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
      }
      h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        font-weight: inherit;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        line-height: 1rem;
        @include mq-sm {
          font-size: 165%;
          line-height: 1.2rem;
        }
        span {
          display: block;
          font-size: 0.6rem;
          margin: 0;
          @include mq-sm {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .body {
      background: #fff;
      border: $border;
      border-top: 0;
      padding: $inner-margin;
      @include mq-lg {
        height: $body-height;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin-bottom: $inner-margin;
      }
      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    @for $i from 1 through $items {
      &--step#{$i} {
        $color: nth($colors, ((($i - 1) % 4) + 1));
        background-color: $color;
        .head::after {
          border-color: $color;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id=timeline>
    <h1>A Flexbox Timeline</h1>
    <p class="leader">All cards must be the same height and width for space calculations on large screens.</p>
    <div class="demo-card-wrapper">
    
        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>01</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Technology</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>02</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Confidence</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>



    
    </div>
</section>
```